# Unable to see the contents in the docker container

Tags: docker

I am newbie to docker and trying to explore the features of docker. I created a container and  stored some data on it and pushed it onto my docker account.

**But, when I am pulling the same container I am not able to see the data which I stored in the container. Why my data is not available?**

Where has my data gone?

**UPDATE**

I performed following steps:

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-11-9F:~$ **sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash**

Unable to find image 'ubuntu' locally
Pulling repository ubuntu

xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete 
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Download complete

root@xxxxxxxxxxxx:

Here I did the changes and then I commited the container

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-07-76-B4:~$ **sudo docker commit xxxxxxxxxxxx ubuntu**
0fd6b6b8acd3dc49947611e61077600a93a6285ebdcf45f1a8f73b4a26274fee

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-07-76-B4:~$ **sudo docker push myrepositoryname/ubuntu**
The push refers to a repository [myrepositoryname/ubuntu] (len: 1)
Sending image list

Please login prior to push:
Username: xxxx
Password: 
Email: xxxxxxxx
Login Succeeded
The push refers to a repository [myrepositoryname/ubuntu] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository myrepositoryname/ubuntu (1 tags)
511136ea3c5a: Image already pushed, skipping 
Image xxxxxxxxxxxx already pushed, skipping
Image xxxxxxxxxxxx already pushed, skipping
Image xxxxxxxxxxxx already pushed, skipping
Pushing tag for rev [xxxxxxxxxxxx] on {https:// repository name}

After it I checked in my docker account, the image got pushed. After that I created a new account and pulled the image (I made the image public). But,I am not getting my data

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-14-1D-8F:~$ **sudo docker login**

Username: xxxx
Password: 
Email: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Account created. Please use the confirmation link we sent to your e-mail to activate it.

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-14-1D-8F:~$ sudo docker login

Username (xxxx): xxxxx

Login Succeeded

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-14-1D-8F:~$ **sudo docker pull myrepositoryname/ubuntu**

Pulling repository myrepositoryname/ubuntu
6d38862b09be: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
6170bb7b0ad1: Download complete 
9cd978db300e: Download complete

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-14-1D-8F:~$ **sudo docker run -i -t myrepositoryname/ubuntu /bin/bash**

root@7b7cc51fbd90:/# cd home/
root@7b7cc51fbd90:/home# ls

I stored my data in /home path but when I am checking there is no data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create an image?

When you `docker run` an image (with `n` file layers, see http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/terms/layer/) you create an `n+1`'th file layer on top of that. That is where you stored your data in. If you `docker stop` your container, that data remains in that layer, and when you re-`docker start` your container the data is still there.

However, if you `docker run` your image again, you make a different container which does not have that data.

Now, you want to send your data to the index (your Docker account). You can only send images, not containers, and the image you used does not contain this data. Therefore, you need to `docker commit` your container to a new image, and the you can `docker push` the resulting image. `docker pull`ing that should give you a startable image containing the data.

Comment: I did not create an image, I have added the steps which I have done, please have look at the update

Comment: you should not commit to `ubuntu`, but to `your_image_name`. I don't know what happens if you try to change the tag from the original ubuntu to your own image, but maybe you just can't. So, the ubuntu that you commit to your_repo is apparently just the original image, which does not have your data.

Comment: as a test, that is fine. I would use a different name to avoid confustion though :).  Have fun